# save file before auto closing workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I want to close my workbook if it's inactive for 1 minute. But before closing, I want to save a backup of it, but make no changes to the original. How can I incorporate this code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=filename, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
```

into this procedure

```
Sub SetTimer()
    Dim bookname
    Dim filename
    DownTime = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00")
    bookname = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    filename = "C:\myhome\backups\" & bookname
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=DownTime, _
      Procedure:="ShutDown", Schedule:=True
End Sub
```

If I insert it into the code, it asks me to save before the timer is done. I want it to ask after the time is done.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are going to assess whether the workbook is inactive or not.  And how you will cancel a scheduled back up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

```
Public Sub SetTimer()
    Dim DownTime As Date
    DownTime = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00")

    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=DownTime, _
      Procedure:="ShutDown", Schedule:=True
End Sub


Private Sub ShutDown()
    ' Be careful about using ActiveWorkbook vs ThisWorkbook vs getting a direct reference to the required workbook.
    Dim bookname As String
    bookname = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    Dim filename As String
    filename = "C:\myhome\backups\" & bookname

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=filename, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
End Sub
```

You need to put the `SaveAs` into a separate method called "ShutDown".  I assume that you put it at the end of the original method.  The call to `Application.OnTime()` runs and schedules `ShutDown()` to be called later on then immediately continues to run the rest of the code in `SetTimer()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just put an event handler in for Workbook_BeforeClose.  I'd personally check to see if it had been altered too so you don't get a bunch of needless backups:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If Not Me.Saved Then
        Me.SaveAs "C:\myhome\backups\" & Me.Name, xlWorkbookNormal
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```